# What are the appropriate adjective and verb that match "load"?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

Hello, everyone. I want to ask a question a little related with the computer. Suppose the requests from the users are shared by more servers as we have deployed more servers. Thus every server "undertakes less load"? Is it right if I say in this way? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Look forward to your reply. Thank you in advance. regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be idiomatic to use a linking verb, for example,

> Every sever *is less loaded*.

You can convey the sense of the load being spread among more servers with:

> The new servers we brought on line *have distributed* the server load.

There are many examples of *reducing* the server load, for example,

> [How To Reduce Server Load Of Your WordPress Blog](http://www.crawlerguys.com/how-to-reduce-server-load-of-your-wordpress-blog/)

Comment: Would you please consider accepting this answer or another one by clicking the green arrow underneath the up/down voting of that answer? That's how we get "paid" on this forum -- by upvotes and acceptance.

Comment: Sorry. I'd really want to do that. But right now I have a reputation of 8 only while upvoting requires a reputation of 15. I am so sorry. I am a newbie here.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer, which is something even a newbie can do! (You'll notice that your reputation went up with the acceptance.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

> loaded

is a commonly used adjective that refers to the load of a server, see for example this [book](http://books.google.fr/books?id=CCKoWbvS5K4C&lpg=PA284&ots=WQYKu3ym7e&dq=less%20loaded%20server&pg=PA284#v=onepage&q=less%20loaded%20server&f=false). There are also algorithms to find the

> Least Loaded Server